# iphone how to check the Airplane mode?

Tags: iphone, airplane-mode

HI ,

i want to check wether Airplane mode is on or not .. how to check that ?

thanks
 + how to check that the user is using WIFI or GPRS OR EDGE . how to differentiate ??

Comment: These questions are very close to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016299/is-it-possible-to-detect-if-the-cellular-network-is-available , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279301/how-to-tell-with-objective-c-if-the-iphone-is-connected-to-a-wifi-network , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178636/way-to-discover-which-internet-connection-type-im-using-on-the-iphone

Comment: this is very close to your: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804398/detect-airplane-mode-on-ios/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you just want show notification, when user is in airplane mode, then it's enough to enable SBUsesNetwork property in your app's plist file. When your code is using network, user is prompted to turn off Airplane mode automatically.

See e.g. [this post](http://blog.sallarp.com/iphone-flight-mode-detection-with-code/).

Comment: it is done only one time. you run the application the alert will come , ... after that you will not get the prompt ...

Comment: Are you sure SBUsesNetwork isn't deprecated or something? It seems Apple doesn't mention it even once anywhere in their documentation...

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *404 Not Found*.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you can check specifically for airplane mode but the [reachability](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Reachability/index.html) example from the iphone adc website enables you to check if the iphone has access to the internet.

Comment: it does'nt tell you that whether the airplane mode in on or off.

Answer (score 2):

This answers the second part of the question - how to tell what type of network the user is on (Wifi or 3g/edge).  It uses the Reachability code from Apple.  Put this in your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in your app delegate:

```
Reachability *curReach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName: @"www.apple.com"];
NetworkStatus netStatus = [curReach currentReachabilityStatus];
switch (netStatus)
{
    case NotReachable:
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Network Status" message:@"Please note: Network access is required to retrieve images." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        break;
    }
    case ReachableViaWiFi:
    case ReachableViaWWAN:
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing this is dangerous because reachabilityWithHostName can block in poor network conditions which can result in your app getting killed by the OS.

Answer (score 2):

For SDK 3.0

(http://bbs.51pda.cn/simple/?t4861.html)

```
#import unistd.h
#include dlfcn.h
#include stdio.h

typedef int (*airType)();
static int (*real_air)() = NULL;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

int status = 0;
void *libHandle = dlopen("/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony", RTLD_LAZY);
real_air = (airType)dlsym(libHandle, "CTPowerGetAirplaneMode");

if(! real_air)
{
printf("something wrong");
}
else
{
status = real_air();
}

printf("%d",status);

return status;
}
```

> debian:~# arm-apple-darwin9-gcc -lobjc -bind_at_load
>   -F"/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks" -framework CoreTelephony test.c -o test