# Block calls in Iphone while application running

Tags: iphone, ios

I need help, working on iPhone app using phoneGap 0.9.6.

while using app I want to block all incoming calls because i do not want the application to be interrupted.
Can any one help.?

Comment: I don't think the users would prefer to give your app more importance than the phone calls.

Comment: I have achieved that using applicationWillResignActive:.:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't do this with any public APIs.

However, your application delegate [will be notified](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillResignActive%3a) when a call comes in, and you can prepare for this (save data, pause, etc.).

Comment: I want to achieve this .Is there any way to achieve this functionality.? It is my application requirement.

Comment: Well, you can't (if you could, you would be making the user's phone useless as a phone...)

Comment: @Rao: you are doing an impossible project. Before starting a project, make sure your project requirement makes sense & achievable.

Comment: I want to make it useless for a small time.As my application is about the questionaire.If the user is filling i want not to be disturbed.

Comment: You can't. (And that's kind of silly.) See my updated answer for some useful information about detecting incoming calls.

Comment: Yes thats what i want to achieve when a call comes it should send a notification so that data in fields can be saved and when call ends we can resume from same point.

Comment: Then you should use `applicationWillResignActive:` (see my link above).

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible? I don't think you can block calls in application.

Maybe you can [detect Airplane mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804398/iphone-detect-airplane-mode) & ask user to switch to Airplane mode if they haven't.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. See also http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/20349-how-do-i-detect-call.html