# isoCountryCode in CTCarrier not returning nil when in Airplane Mode

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios11

I am using isoCountryCode in CTCarrier in iPhone 6 (iOS 11.4.1). The value if isoCountryCode is returned as "in" when the SIM is inserted and the Airplane mode is turned on.

As per [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretelephony/ctcarrier/1620317-isocountrycode), the value for this property is `nil` if any of the following apply.

- The device is in Airplane mode. (valid in my case)
- There is no SIM card in the device.
- The device is outside of cellular service range.

Need help to know if I understood the document correctly. If yes, then why am I getting isoCountryCode as "in" in Airplane Mode?

---

I have filed a bug with Apple for this issue.

https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=47138150

Comment: just check is in Airplane Mode if yes consider it as nil

Comment: @SPatel: How do I check if Airplane Mode is enabled?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804398/detect-airplane-mode-on-ios

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37025377/how-to-detect-airplane-mode-flight-mode-in-ios-swift

Comment: @SPatel: Can you point out the the answer in the links you have provided? I could just find workarounds.

Comment: It looks like the documentation needs to be updated or the behaviour of their framework needs to be changed.  Log a bug with Apple.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38893076/how-to-get-the-country-code-from-simcard-programatically-in-ios-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you understand it correctly. isoCountryCode should be nil in flight mode.

Comment: So why am I getting isoCountryCode as "in" when the Airplane Mode is turned on?

Answer (score 0):

Apple Docs are not clear enough in this case. `isoCountryCode` does not change when you roaming. It means that OS should only get your carriers code only once. Probably it will be nil when you insert new SIM card when phone Airplane mode is turned on. I'm not an expert in this field, but most probably SIM can hold MCC/MNC code which is statically linked with country. Some test: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5829063/1980246