# How to differentiate the Airplane mode from No Service in React Native iOS?

Tags: react-native

For business rules reasons, I need to check whether user has no signal from carrier or purposefully has Airplane mode enabled.

Users have a tendency to use Airplane mode to bypass some functions. In Android, I was able to block those behaviours with no further issues, but so far on this React Native-based app for iOS devices, I'm having issues.

Any work-around is welcome.

Application info:

```
"react-native": "^0.64.0",
"@react-native-community/netinfo": "^6.0.0",
"react-native-system-setting": "^1.7.6",
```

Comment: Would this work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37025893/10718641

Comment: It would but I don't know how I can access this system configuration thru react-native.

Comment: You would need to write a native module for it https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios