# How to be notified when iPhone enters airplane mode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, airplane-mode

Is there a way for my app to be notified when the device enters (and leaves) airplane mode?

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264053/detect-if-iphone-is-in-airplane-mode/10588802#10588802 as well as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095109/reachability-airplane-mode-3g-vs-wifi#comment17796209_13095109

Answer (score 6):

You can use Apple's [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) code to see if a user has network access when they open your app or similar.

There is however no notification/trigger which your app can intercept/run arbitary code when a user enters or leaves airplane mode in the Settings.